# how to count entries in Date Array List on weekly bases in android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have:

```
 List<Dates> DatesList = new ArrayList<>();
```

that contains number of Date entries (there are repeated entries) like:

```
2016-05-01, 2016-05-01, 2016-05-01, 2016-05-02, 2016-05-03, 2016-05-04, 2016-05-04, 2016-05-04, 2016-05-01, ... ETC
```

my target is to count the entries per every week (7 days) starting from the first date in the list. is there any way for this?

I just can't find any plan in my mind to achieve such a goal. how to move?

Comment: Show me you've thought about the solution and I'll be happy to help

Comment: Should the weeks be demarcated by a fixed day (e.g. Monday)? Or should we start counting 7-day periods from the oldest date in the list?

Comment: parse to some date type (Calendar)... group by year and then week of the year ... count mebers of the group ... seems like a basic programming excercise

Comment: The point is that I can't find an approach to start with, I I had to change this list string to list of dates, but I just can't find the next step .. I thought may I can divide the big list to sublists based on weeks then get list.size() for each list .. but the problem is I don't know how many sub lists I will need as the range of dates will always differ! I thought also if I can make a loop to put the first entry in a calendar then move 7 days forward .. but I don't know how to split the list in this point.

Comment: @adriaan Koster, No I just needed 7 days from the oldest one.

Comment: @Selvin, I will try you solution, but is there a List of Calendar values?

Comment: then order the list, parse to some date type , take a differences in days from given day ... now use sparse array and increment the position of (int) (diff / 7) in the loop ... sparsearray[x] would return the numbers of the event in x week ago

Comment: @Selvin: what if the dates span more than a year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach would be to first sort the list then iterate over the items and keep track of the weekly counts.

```
long WEEK_IN_MILLIS = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
List<Date> dates = ...
Collections.sort(dates);
int weekNumber = 1;
int counter = 0;
Date weekStart = null;
for(Date date : dates) {        
    if (weekStart == null) {
        weekStart = date;          
    }
    else {
        long interval = date.getTime() - weekStart.getTime();
        if (interval > WEEK_IN_MILLIS) {
            System.out.printf("Week %s has %s dates in it", weekNumber, counter);
            weekNumber++;
            weekStart = date;
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
    counter++;
}
```

EDIT: changed `counter - 1` to `counter`in the `System.our.printf` statement

Comment: many thanks Adrian, this achieved my goal, I had only to change it to interval >= WEEK_IN_MILLIS .. to not incluse the first day of the next week. much appreciated

Comment: Take another look. I think it should remain > but you should use `counter` instead of `counter-1`.